# COleDateTime behaviour when using maximum date

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to understand an ASSERT that i'm having when i call

```
COleDateTime time;
this->m_wndDate.GetTime(time);
```

and the date in my datePicker is 31/12/9999 (format DD/MM/YYYY) the function

```
BOOL CDateTimeCtrl::GetTime(_Out_ COleDateTime& timeDest) const
```

is showing me `ASSERT(timeDest.GetStatus() == COleDateTime::valid); (winctrl5.cpp, line 181)` but accordingly to the documentation it is a valid date.

I can't understand why this is happening. Does anyone encountered this issue before?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** the method `GetTime` is called when the user changes the DatePicker.

```
ON_NOTIFY(DTN_DATETIMECHANGE, IDC_DATE, OnDatetimechangeDate)
```

...

```
void WDlgRelParamVar::OnDatetimechangeDate(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    LPNMDATETIMECHANGE pNMDATE = (LPNMDATETIMECHANGE)pNMHDR;
    COleDateTime time;
    this->m_wndDate.GetTime(time);
    ...
```

Comment: Your timezone is going to have an affect, SO users *really* need to mention their country in their SO profile.  It might no longer be valid after conversion to UTC, like COleDateTime does.  You should check first by using the GetTime(LPSYSTEMTIME) overload.

Comment: @HansPassant i'm from Brazil so UTC-03:00, it only hits the assert when the date is set to 31/12/9999, would the timezone affect even in that case?

Comment: Are you running on XP? What is the version of Common Controls (check manifest)?

Comment: Try using  DDX_DateTimeCtrl to see if you face the same issue. Please note there was a date time picker bug in CommonControls 6.0

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin I'm using Win7, Visual studio 10 and the version of my Common Controls is 6.0 . I can't find any mention to this bug, can you give me a link? Thank you!

Comment: It has been a while... I could not find it now. Anyways I'd suggest using DDX_DateTimeCtr in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the DateTime picker control is not properly initialized at the time you call `GetTime()` on it.

Try running the following code snippet to see if it works as expected:

```
COleDateTime dt(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);
COleDateTime::DateTimeStatus st = dt.GetStatus();
ASSERT(st == COleDateTime::valid);
```

You have not provided the code that sets up the input format for Date Time Picker. You need to use `m_wndDate.SetFormat(_T("dd/MM/yyyy"));` to set the format. Please note it is case sensitive. So your format **DD/MM/YYYY is wrong**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work!The default COleDateTime constructor set the object to 0 (midnight, 30 December 1899) so it doesn't need an extra initialization.
I believe maybe the problem is a conversion of SYSTEMTIME to COleDateTIme inside the function CDateTimeCtrl::GetTime.

Comment: I believe the your problem is related to setting format for `CDateTimeCtrl`

Comment: It should be dd/MM/yyyy not  DD/MM/YYYY. Read this for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb761726#dtp_format_chars

Comment: FYI: The code snippet was provided just for you to make sure that COleDateTime works as expected and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry i wrote DD/MM/YYYY in my question just to show that i'm using the format with days first in case that matters but in my code i'm using SetFormat(_T("dd/MM/yyyy")).

Comment: When do you call GetTime() method? Post more details so we can help you out.